# Upload image from local system using ng2-ckeditor

Tags: angular, ckeditor, image-uploading

I'm using Angular 4. I have installed ng2-ckEditor. Now I want to upload an image from the local system using ng2-ckEditor.
Please give me the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload file using php or else. Because you can not use ckfinder for that. Because whenever you run the project you can not use the node_modules as external resource.

You hae to simply create a php file and put code into that php file

1. put this code in your .ts file

*Code*

```
// image upload using ckeditor
"uploadUrl": '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',
"filebrowserImageUploadUrl": 'http://localhost/ckeditor/imageupload.php'
```

2. Create php file on root and put this code into that.

*Code*

```
<?php

$uploadedFile = $_FILES['upload'];
$path = 'http://localhost/ckeditor/';
move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile['tmp_name'], $path.$uploadedFile)) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, 'http://localhost/ckeditor/".$uploadedFile['name']."', '');</script>";
}

?>
```